# PAN with Linux, iOS, Bluetooth, Bonjour, GameKit -- Possible?

Tags: ios, linux, bluetooth, gamekit, bonjour

So I read different takes on this matter (I think I read all the related questions on SO). Can I connect in a PAN - Can I write an app that will connect - my linux machine and my iOS device via bluetooth? Using or not using Bonjour or GameKit.

Few requisites:

1. iOS devices are *not* jailbroken.
2. iOS devices may or may not have the hotspot/tethering feature enabled (which as far as I have gathered is dictated by the Broadband provider -- i.e. if you pay you can tether your connection).
3. iOS can run a custom made app that uses documented APIs.
4. Bluetooth can be activated by hand by the iOS device user.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> iOS 3.0 provides support for headsets (mono/stereo), networking via the PAN/BNEP protocol and support for "Made for iPhone" devices which require a proprietary Bluetooth protocol. Still, not even basic OBEX support is included (available with any low-price mobile phone), and no API is available to connect to arbitrary Bluetooth devices. It also extents the GameKit API to allow for iOS-to-iOS communication.

[iPhone Bluetooth Information](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneBluetooth)

Personally, I would instead use wifi + bonjour. [Here's a tutorial about implementing it,](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) some of the code can be pretty gross, but once you get the boilerplate out of the way, it "just works", which is always a feel good moment.

Comment: Thanks you Sneakyness, wifi is indeed much simpler to use, I agree, but I need BT. The above quote from the BTSTack says everything/nothing. I still can't get a definitive answer on whether I can just create a PAN between my linux and my iOS and then, in this PAN, I can do what I need via TCP/IP. Do you have any more insights? Thanks.

Comment: My insight is to stop speculating around on the internet and start programming ;)

Comment: @JoeSlav, did you get PAN working between iOS and linux?

Comment: No :) Gave up and went for a standard wifi server-client arch